# Receive a notification issue and open a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-notifications, android-push-notification

I am working on application notification when a user receives a friend request notification and clicks on the notification the application has to redirect him to the user profile who have sent the request.

I am facing more than a problem:
first, if the application running in the background the receiver can receive a notification, but if the application is running, the receiver application crash after the sender sends a notification and it doesn't show the notification.

the second problem is that when the receiver clicks on the notification the application open and stay in the main activity at the default fragment.
knowing in my application the main activity contains multiple.
I have created a fragment for the user profile, and I have to pass a user id to open this fragment, so it will direct to the user profile who send the friend request, but it seems that there is no user id received.

Her is the class FirebaseMessagingService code:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    String notification_title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String notification_message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

    String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
    String from_user_id = remoteMessage.getData().get("from_user_id");

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
                    .setContentTitle(notification_title)
                    .setContentText(notification_message);

    Intent intent = new Intent(click_action);
    intent.putExtra("user_id", from_user_id);
    intent.putExtra("From", "notifyFrag");

    PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    int mNotificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
}
```

And in the Main activity:

```
    @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(getIntent().getExtras() != null) {

        String from_user_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_id");
        String type = getIntent().getStringExtra("From");

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (type != null) {
            switch (type) {
                case "notifyFrag":
                    UserProfileFragment fragment = new UserProfileFragment();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);

                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("user_id", from_user_id);
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                    transaction.commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The crash error is:

[image]
it point to:
mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
in class FirebaseMessagingService.

So please if someone can help!

---

I updated the class FirebaseMessagingService code and now the app doesn't crash, I am able to receive a notification in both cases if the app is running or close. but if I click in the notification nothing happen

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    Intent intent;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    final int NOTIFY_ID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis(); // ID of notification
    String notification_id = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id); // default_channel_id

    String notification_title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String notification_message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

    String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
    String from_user_id = remoteMessage.getData().get("from_user_id");

    if(mNotifyMgr == null){
        mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel mChannel = mNotifyMgr.getNotificationChannel(notification_id);

        if (mChannel == null) {
            mChannel = new NotificationChannel(notification_id, notification_title, importance);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            mNotifyMgr.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notification_id)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_ic)
                        .setContentTitle(notification_title)
                        .setContentText(notification_message)
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        intent = new Intent(click_action);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("user_id", from_user_id);
        intent.putExtra("From", "notifyFrag");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    }
    else {
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notification_id)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_ic)
                .setContentTitle(notification_title)
                .setContentText(notification_message)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        intent = new Intent(click_action);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("user_id", from_user_id);
        intent.putExtra("From", "notifyFrag");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    }

    //Set an ID for the notification
    mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
    mNotifyMgr.notify(NOTIFY_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting error because you haven't added small icon to notification

```
  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.your_icon)
```

update your code

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
                    .setContentTitle(notification_title).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.your_icon)
                    .setContentText(notification_message);
```

[developer](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar) , [oneSignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-icons)

Comment: thanks, now the app didn't crash, but I got another error No Channel found

No Channel found for pkg=sma_project, channelId=SWME_CH_01, id=709021503, tag=null, opPkg=sma_project, callingUid=10079, userId=0, incomingUserId=0, notificationUid=10079, notification=Notification(channel=SWME_CH_01 pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x0 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)

Comment: from android 8.0 you need to add notification channel
 please ref this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#ManageChannels

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Answer (score 0):

Set *Small Icon* and *Create notification channel* for that. Since [Android 8.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Oreo) (Oreo), a notification needs a Channel:

```
Intent broadcastIntent = "Your Intent";
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, notificationId, broadcastIntent,
                                                         PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationManager notificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(String.valueOf(notificationId),
                                                          message,
                                                          NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, String.valueOf(notificationId))
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_status)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setContentText(message)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri);
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
```